# I have a Boolean variable to temporarily disable my mouse listener but it remembers wher i clicked

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener

I am using a Boolean canclick mouse variable to temporarily disable my `mouse listener`, but it seems like when i re-enable the `mouse listener` it remembers where i click:

```
class MouseHelper extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(!canclick)
        {
            return;
        }

        int a=e.getX();
        int b=e.getY();
        if(a>=473&&a<=502&&b>=139&&b<=153&&start==true)
        {
            runonce=1;
            repaint();
            start=false;
        }
```

So this is where i set the canclick as false after its done displaying the correct screen it resets the `canclick` to `true`:

```
    if(runonce==2)
    {
        canclick=false;
        System.out.println("Set as false");
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,40));
            g.drawString("Correct!",325,250);
        try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        runonce=1;
    }
    if(runonce==1)
    {
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,10));
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0,0,1000,1000);
        drawboxes(g);
        says();
        s=10;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(colr.get(colr.size()-1),401,s);
        count=Integer.toString(level+1);
        g.drawString("Level:"+count,401,s+10);
        canclick=true;

    }

}
```

My problem is that when i click during the correct screen, where `canclick` is set as `false`, when `canclick` is set as true again it remembers allt he place that i clicked.

Comment: what behaviour causes you to think the clicked places are remembered?

Comment: Also, where is `canclick` declared and how does your second code snippet fit in with the first one?

Answer (score 2):

You're sleeping in the event dispatch thread. This completely freezes the GUI, and prevents Swing from dispatching events. This means that while the GUI is frozen, the events pile up in a queue until it becomes responsive again. At this time, your listener gets called with all the events that have been queued.

Don't sleep in the event dispatch thread. If you want to change some state after a delay, use a Swing timer to fire an event that will update the state after this delay, but keep the GUI responsive during that delay.